# Multiple lines for large titles in navigation bars in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11

Is it possible to have the new large titles for navigation bars in iOS 11 show multiple lines? The App Store app does this but I can't find anything in the current documentation to do this. The standard behavior just shows one line with ellipsis if it's too long.

[image]

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: If it can help here's what I did a another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647001/631927

Answer (score 5):

Add following code into viewWillAppear:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    self.title = "Hello big text, For navigation large style bar"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)]

    var count = 0
    for item in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
        for sub in item.subviews{
            if sub is UILabel{
                if count == 1 {
                    break;
                }
                let titleLab :UILabel = sub as! UILabel
                titleLab.numberOfLines = 0
                titleLab.text = self.title
                titleLab.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                count = count + 1
            }
        }

    }
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutSubviews()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Facing issue with back button will update soon..

Comment: Any update for the back button issue? I can only get it to work in the viewdidappear, which only applies after the view is visible and thus looks blocky.

Comment: maybe you can just use break where you've assigned the count.

Comment: this does not work, the label goes multiline but nav bar does not increase its height @Rahul_Chandnani

Comment: Agreed with @ShahzaibQureshi

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this simply by using a non-public API. Use at your own risk:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      title = "Thunderbox Entertaiment"
      navigationItem.enableMultilineTitle()
   }

}
```

```
extension UINavigationItem {
   
   func enableMultilineTitle() {
      setValue(true, forKey: "__largeTitleTwoLineMode")
   }
   
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: private api may lead to unpredictable results like crashes and review rejection