# How to line break long large title in iOS 13?

Tags: uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, ios13

As title, is there a way to split long large titles in UINavigationBar?

I tried all those methods, working for iOS 11 but none of them seem work to me on iOS 13

[How to set multi line Large title in navigation bar? ( New feature of iOS 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901318/how-to-set-multi-line-large-title-in-navigation-bar-new-feature-of-ios-11/51295457)

Comment: same issue for me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. So far I created a custom Label view that imitates the default ios behaviour

Comment: Would you be willing to share your UILabel code?

Comment: Same for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588368/how-to-convert-navbar-large-title-to-multi-line-centre-aligned/

Comment: This code worked for me just by setting navigation item's value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792576/17244346

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a custom view (UILabel) to your title as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34298491/12032813).